# why the pnpm did not update the dependencies

Tags: typescript, pnpm

I am using this pnpm (`v8.5.0`) command to update the project dependencies:

```
pnpm update
```

and the log shows the dependencies was udpated:

```
> pnpm update
 WARN  GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2Freact error (ECONNRESET). Will retry in 10 seconds. 2 retries left.
Packages: +1 -1
+-
Progress: resolved 1027, reused 1005, downloaded 1, added 1, done

dependencies:
- rd-component 0.1.55
+ rd-component 0.1.56
```

but the dependencies of the project still using the legacy lib:

[image]

I was facing some issue when import newest component. this is my `package.json` config:

```
"rd-component": "^0.1.56",
```

why did this happen? does anyone facing the similiar issue?